# List of Kubernetes RBAC rule verbs

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts, rbac

I want to give my application limited access to get the replicas of different statefulsets (and maybe deployment) and if necessary scale them up or down.

I have created ServiceAccount, Rolebinding and Role for this but I can't find the complete list of rule verbs ("get", "watch", "list", "update") and what are their limitations, for example can I use `update` for scaling or I need another verb? And where can I find a list or table that described these verbs?

My yaml file:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: scaler-role
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace  | quote }}
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["statefulset"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "update"]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb) is the list of RBAC verbs:

[image: RBAC verbs]

For scaling, I think you'll need write permissions (`create`, `update` and `patch`) along with read permissions (`get`, `list` and `watch`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is strange that there is no actual table that clearly and in detail described all of these verbs.

Comment: @AVarf please see my update using the k8s api server directly. I ended up creating a kubectl plugin that makes it easy and might be of use to others.

Answer (score 69):

You can get quite a bit of info via this:

```
kubectl api-resources --sort-by name -o wide
```

The above `api-resources` command is explicit and easy to grep. The complete list of possible verbs can be obtained thus:

```
$ kubectl api-resources --no-headers --sort-by name -o wide | sed 's/.*\[//g' | tr -d "]" | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq
create
delete
deletecollection
get
list
patch
update
watch
```

The *Resource Operations* section of API reference docs (eg https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/) talks a little bit about them but doesn't mention `deletecollection` (btw: see [interesting info about `deletecollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131185/869951); suggests that whenever you give `delete`, you should give `deletecollection` permission too, if the resource supports it).

The [Determine the Request Verb](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb) section of [Authorization Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) does briefly mention `deletecollection`, as well as a half a dozen more verbs (such as `escalate` as pointed out rightfully by @RoryMcCune) which, unfortunately, do not show up in output of `kubectl api-resources -o wide` command.

BTW the `api-resources` command also lists the short names of commands, such as `svc` for `services`.

### Update May 2023:

Another less user-friendly but more complete way of getting the verbs is by directly querying the API server:

1. in one terminal, start a proxy for the API server; eg `kubectl proxy --port=8080`
2. in another terminal, use `curl` on `/api/v1` and `/apis`

**For core resources (configmaps, etc):**

Use `curl -s lo calhost:8080 /api/v1` to get json with the verbs for each core resource type name. Eg (if you have `jq`)

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/v1 | jq '.resources[] | [.name, (.verbs | join(" "))] | join(" = ")' -r
bindings = create
componentstatuses = get list
configmaps = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch
endpoints = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch
...
```

**For the non-core resources (deployments, CRD, etc):**

Say you want the verbs for deployments, you know that the API group for deployments is `apps`. First get the versioned group name for that API using `curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis`. Eg (if you have `jq`)

````
```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis | jq '.groups[].preferredVersion.groupVersion' -r | grep ^apps
apps/v1
```
````

Use this to query the API of that group for verbs by using `curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis/VERSIONED_API` ie in the above example `curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1`. Eg (if you have `jq`, the jq is the same),

````
```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1 | jq '.resources[] | [.name, (.verbs | join(" "))] | join(" = ")' -r
controllerrevisions = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch
daemonsets = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch
daemonsets/status = get patch update
deployments = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch
deployments/scale = get patch update
deployments/status = get patch update
...
```
````

BTW the page https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/ documents how to use Python, Java etc instead of curl.

I created a kubectl plugin, for the use case where one wants to get the verbs for a specific resource type: https://github.com/schollii/my-devops-lab/blob/main/kubernetes/kubectl-verbs. Eg

```
$ kubectl verbs configmaps
configmaps = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch

$ kubectl verbs deployments apps
deployments = create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch
deployments/scale = get patch update
deployments/status = get patch update
```

The file has instructions to install it as a plugin. It is a simple bash script.

Comment: Worth noting that that command doesn't seem to catch verbs which only work within certain APIs (e.g. the escalate verb in RBAC)

Comment: @RoryMcCune thanks for pointing that out I extended the answer

Comment: Also missing are verbs for subresources, like `pods/log`

Comment: thanks @yurez for pointing that out, I extended the answer to provide those, let me know if I still missed some

Answer (score 5):

A list of verbs can be found here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#review-your-request-attributes

and a brief description can be found here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb

I have a role that I use for updating the docker image tag for deployments which looks like this (I don't use mine to create the deployment, just to patch the image tag)

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: deployer
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "patch"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to this, to know the **full list of verbs for apiGroups and resources on your running cluster**, including any additional one introduced with operators or CRD, you can do the following.

Open in a terminal:

```bash
kubectl proxy
```

Then on a different terminal, you can run:

```bash
# List all API urls
curl http://localhost:8001/ | yq '.paths[]'

# List all objects and verbs for an API path like /api/v1
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1 | yq '.resources[] | [{"resources":.name,"verbs":.verbs}]'
```

If you want a script that lists all in a single place in a nice way, run this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Remember to run on another terminal before this script:
# kubectl proxy

set -euo pipefail

# Show Kubernetes server version
echo -n '# '
kubectl version --short 2>/dev/null | grep 'Server'

for url in $(curl -s http://localhost:8001/ | yq '.paths[]' | xargs) ; do 
    [ "$url" == "/metrics" ] && continue
    doc=$(curl -s http://localhost:8001$url)

    # If URL doesn't publish info, skip
    [ "$doc" == "ok" ] && continue

    # Remove from apiGroup prefix (/, /api/v1, /apis/) and suffix ( /v1, /v1beta1)
    apiGroup=$(echo $url | sed 's/\/api\/v1//' | sed 's/\/apis\///' | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\/v[0-9]*\(beta[0-9]\+\)\?$//'  )

    # Get permissions and format them nicely in YAML
    yaml=$(echo "$doc" | yq -M '[.resources[] | {"apiGroups":["'$apiGroup'"], "resources":[.name],"verbs":.verbs}] | .. style="double" | .[].* style="flow"' 2>/dev/null ||:);
    
    # TODO: group resources from the same apiGroup with the same verbs together

    # If document is empty, skip it
    [ "$yaml" == "[]" ] && continue

    echo ""
    echo "# $url"
    echo "$yaml"
done
```

You can also find that script on this gist:
https://gist.github.com/vicenteherrera/0bfe2762ecd5794eba65ed19d0d51188

When you execute it, you can save the output on a file:

```
./list_verbs.sh >verbs.yaml
```

Here is a brief example of the output:

```yaml
# /apis/templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
- apiGroups: ["templates.gatekeeper.sh"]
  resources: ["constrainttemplates"]
  verbs: ["delete", "deletecollection", "get", "list", "patch", "create", "update", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["templates.gatekeeper.sh"]
  resources: ["constrainttemplates/status"]
  verbs: ["get", "patch", "update"]
```

Then you can just copy and paste a YAML block from that file to your Kubernetes role, it already is in the format expected for the role.

Answer (score 2):

You can type this command and check VERBS column

```
kubectl api-resources --api-group=rbac.authorization.k8s.io -o wide
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Mac/WSL/etc.

1. Run: kubectl proxy &
2. Run: curl http://127.0.0.1:8001 -k | grep -v 'paths' | grep '"' | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,//g' | sort | while read line ; do kubectl get --raw ${line} ; done | jq | less
3. Search for the api you need in less to see the verbs.

Comment: Why would you do a "curl -k" on an HTTP (non-SSL) request? I would suggest a "curl -s", to avoid the additional messages that curl prints.